# rails5 の production環境で uninitialized constant error が発生

Tags: ruby-on-rails

rails5　の production環境で uninitialized constant errorが発生します。
development環境では、エラーは発生しておらず、原因をお伺いいたしたく、投稿致します。

◆ コマンド

```
# rails restart
# bundle exec rails runner [クラス名].[メソッド名] -e production
uninitialized constant Rails::Command::RunnerCommand::[クラス名]
```

※ 「-e production」を抜いて同コマンドを実行した際は正常終了します。
※ [クラス名]は、lib配下に配置しています。

◆ application.rb設定

```
config.load_defaults 5.1
config.i18n.default_locale = :ja
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
config.eager_load_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
config.paths.add 'lib', eager_load: true
```

また、解析に必要なパラメータが他にあれば、教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bd5eba1adff8fa72429f5889ae26097e9756ceb0/railties/lib/rails/engine/configuration.rb#L75

などを見ていると、 rails 5+ では、 eager_load_paths や auto_load_paths は、 config.paths から勝手に生成される前提の様子です。

ですので、 `config.paths.add 'lib', eager_load: true` だけがあればよく、この形式のみの paths の設定を行うのが良いと思います。

Answer (score 0):

おそらく自己解決したので、備忘を兼ねて回答を記載します。

◆ application.rb(修正前)

```
config.load_defaults 5.1
config.i18n.default_locale = :ja
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
config.eager_load_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
config.paths.add 'lib', eager_load: true
```

◆ application.rb(修正後)

```
config.load_defaults 5.1
config.i18n.default_locale = :ja
#config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
config.eager_load_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/"]
config.paths.add 'lib', eager_load: true
```

実施したのは、以下3点です。
※ autoload_pathsをコメントアウト(Rails5では廃止されているため)
https://qiita.com/joooee0000/items/3ab0f3d791e0d0beb639
※ eager_load_pathsの「~lib/**/」を「~lib/」に修正
※ 本番環境再起動

なぜ、これがうまくいったかについては現時点で不明です。
お分かりになる方がいれば記載いただければ幸いです。